# Using document ready to execute functions from different JS files

Tags: jquery

I am working on a project and my aim is to load a few elements together so that the don't pop up individually. So lets say I have have function `loadA` inside of a JS file A and function `loadB` inside of JS file B. Now inside JS file C I know I could run

`$(document).ready(loadA);
 $(document).ready(loadb);`

and that would work but is there a way to have both inside one ready function without it failing?

Comment: `$(function () { loadA(); loadB() })`? NB: `$()` is the preferred syntax to use `ready` (according to [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/))

Answer (score 0):

Having those two calls to `$(document).ready` in separate file works just fine.
 However it's not practical : it's hard to anticipate which call will occur first, what would be the order of those calls (easy to determine with 2 calls, not that much when there are way more).

I usually have a single `document.ready.js` file with this type of content :

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
  myFunc();
  myFunc2();
  myFunc3();
});
```

and `myFunc`, `myFunc2` and `myFunc3` can be defined in other files. This allows you to easily keep track of which function is called in what order, making it more maintainable.

NB

there's also a shorthand syntax if you are interested :

```
$(()=>{
  myFunc();
  myFunc2();
  myFunc3();
});
```